# How to set different wallpapers for each monitor Ubuntu 20.xx?

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-background

I am using a dual monitor setup in my Ubuntu system. I was trying to set different wallpapers for each monitor, but I couldn't do it. I tried [HydraPaper](https://gitlab.com/gabmus/HydraPaper), but it is not working.

Is there any other way to do it?